# Why Clocking block is not blocking?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Back to back assignment on interface signal using clocking block as blocking statement, but not working as expected.

For the below code I expect to set 1, but it is not set

Result:

At time 95: set to 1

then without waiting for clocking block, at timestamp 95, moved to the next statement to set 0.

Need help on this

```
interface intf(input clk);
   logic done;
   clocking smp_cb @(posedge clk); 
   endclocking
endinterface

module top;

   bit clk;
   always #5 clk =~clk;

   intf intf_inst(.*);

   initial begin
      repeat(10)@(posedge clk);
      $display("[%0t] set 1", $realtime);
      assign_intf(1);
      $display("[%0t] set 0", $realtime);
      assign_intf(0);
      //$display("[%0t] set 1", $realtime);
      //assign_intf(1);
      //$display("[%0t] set 0", $realtime);
      //assign_intf(0);
      repeat(10)@(posedge clk);
      $stop;
   end

   task assign_intf(logic val);
      intf_inst.done <= val;
      @( intf_inst.smp_cb);
      //@(posedge intf_inst.clk);
   endtask

   initial $monitor(" Monitor: [%0t] done_sig value %0d", $realtime, intf_inst.done);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you should not be mixing event controls `@(posedge clk)` and clocking block events `@(intf_inst.smp_cb)` in the same process. If you intend on using a clocking block, your only interaction with signals should be through the clocking block. Otherwise you wind up with race conditions between the *raw* signals and the clocking block signals.

In your example, both events get triggered at the same time-step, but not simultaneously. At the point you call the assign_intf task, the clocking block event has not triggered yet.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with a different edge on my trigger (negedge) and clocking block (posedge), it worked and assigns value as I expected. When both are same edge, it failed.

Comment: the correct fix for this code:
 `initial begin
      repeat(10)@(intf_inst.smp_cb); `